# Java Program completely stuck

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

I have noticed a very strange problem that sometimes(once per few days) happens to my java program. For some reason, it gets totally stuck. It is multi threaded application, i have got no clue what might cause this.

What are the symptoms:

- Even if I have scheduled code to just print something in console, it doesn't show up at all
- I run the program by .bat file and I have got shutdown hook, first thing that is done in run() is print in console by Logger. When I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which normally stops the program, completely nothing happens.
- I use following settings(`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=5009`) to debug program by Intellij IDEA. It was connected before the stuck and after program stucked there is 0 response, Pausing program doesn't give any effect.
- I tried to connect to the program with Java VisualVM, after choosing the program, visual VM stucked and there is no response.

I use jre 1.8.0_51, program is run with following arguments:
`-Xmx8g -Xms4g -Xmn2g -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -Xnoclassgc -XX:+AggressiveOpts`

Any clues?

Comment: Time to do some super-aggressive logging, I think. Otherwise, I'm not sure how we can help you based on the scant information and no code presented.

Comment: Logging stops to work, after the stuck. I am just trying to find out what should i look for. When i had infinite loops or dead locks in the past, it was possible to use debugger or profiler and in this case it is not possible.

Comment: If you are debugging from eclipse you can see all running threads and their actual status and which is active. You can try to limit your program to one core and hope you see which one it is or maybe it does not even occur.

Comment: I am debugging from Intellij IDEA. To see status of the threads, JVM must be paused(or reach the break point). When i am trying to pause the program during the stuck(which of course normally works fine), nothing happens. So i cannot see what is actually happening, if anything.

Comment: How about using a profiler?

Comment: "I tried to connect to the program with Java VisualVM, after choosing the program, visual VM stucked and there is no response." - That's what i wrote in the first post.

Comment: try `jstack -F` or ctrl+break/send SIGBREAK (assuming unix) to force a stack trace.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it out as soon as i have the occasion.